# How to deserialize a transaction hex to a readable object(or a json object) with Java language

Tags: transaction, java

Assuming I have a serialized transaction in hexadecimal, how can I deserialize it in Java?

Answer (score 1):

What language are you using?

There are packages written in JS, Rust, Python etc.
All have methods to fetch and decode Transaction info into an object.

Comment: I use Java. Unfortunately, I didn’t find Java SDK.